# Split lines on separator but just two slices

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I want the delimiter to work only once so the line can be split into only two parts. I tried something with awk with `=` as delimiter, but it splits the line into three parts if there is second `=`.

Given the file `file.txt`:

```
first="text"
line="book"
red=cat
nice="lineelrk="
```

I am doing:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F"=" '{print $1,$2}' | while read arg arg2
do 
echo "Read first user as $arg2"
done
```

My goal is to have `arg2` take each of these values for file.txt:

```
"text"
"book"
cat
"lineelrk="
```

Comment: not very sure what is the most representative title, won't touch it any more though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `while read` because you want to do some stuff with the variables, not just printing them. If it was the case, simple `awk` would suffice.

But if you want to have a bash variable with the content, you can do the following:

You can set `=` as `IFS` (internal field separator) and use `read` with two parameters. This way, the first slice will be stored in the first variable and the second one variable will contain the rest of the parts:

```
while IFS="=" read -r arg arg2
do 
    echo "Read first user as $arg2"
done < file.txt
```

If you are going to use just the second one, you can call the first variable something like `_` (dummy name), so that it is clear that you are not using that info:

```
$ while IFS="=" read -r _ arg; do echo "-- $arg --"; done < file.txt
-- "text" --
-- "book" --
-- cat --
-- "lineelrk=" --
```

Comment: Curious to know, what if I have only one line ex. cat file.txt |grep -w "nice". How to do it without while loop?

Comment: @user1595858 then you could say something like `while IFS=.... do ... done < <(grep -w "nice" file.txt)`

Answer (score 2):

For what you THINK you want, this would be the way to implement it:

```
$ cut -d= -f2- file | while IFS= read -r arg2; do echo "$arg2"; done
"text"
"book"
cat
"lineelrk="
```

but it's almost certainly the wrong way to do whatever it is you're trying to do and you should instead just use awk instead of a shell loop. In which case, take your pick:

```
$ awk '{name=value=$0; sub(/=.*/,"",name); sub(/[^=]+=/,"",value); print name ":" value}' file
first:"text"
line:"book"
red:cat
nice:"lineelrk="

$ awk 'match($0,/=/){name=substr($0,1,RSTART-1); value=substr($0,RSTART+1); print name ":" value}' file
first:"text"
line:"book"
red:cat
nice:"lineelrk="
```

Comment: Nice answer but a bit overkill for OPs requirements

Comment: OP is almost certainly asking us to help him implement the wrong solution.

Comment: For your first solution it may be better to do `while IFS= read -r arg2; do echo "$arg2"; done < <(cut -d= -f2- test)` so you don't lose scope on variables in the loop.As you've said OP probably wants to do something more than they are asking.

Comment: idk, he might be happy with `while IFS='=' read -r skip arg2; do ...` too and not use `cut` at all, but it'd still probably be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/[^=]*=/,"")}1' file
"text"
"book"
cat
"lineelrk="
```

It remove all up to first `=`

Comment: Sed would probably be better for this`sed 's/[^=]*=//'`